# Java ActiveMQ avoid new connection start

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
public class MessageSender {
    public static ConnectionFactory factory = null;
    public static Connection connection = null;
    public static Session session = null;
    public static Destination destination = null;
    public static MessageProducer producer = null;

    public static void sendMessage(String queueName,String messageContent) {
        try {
            factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                    ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);            
            connection = factory.createConnection();            
            connection.start();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            destination = session.createQueue(queueName);        
            producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
            message.setText(messageContent);
            producer.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent: " + message.getText() );     

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my java JMS code to push messages to the queue.  Every time I want push message to queue, I used to invoke like below

```
MessageSender.sendMessage("orderdetailsQueue","OrderReceivedIdB6789");
```

so  for each message it invoke `new connection.start()`. How can I generalize this?

Comment: what exactly you want to do when you say generalize? The code you have shown uses Template pattern which is generic enough.

Comment: for each message it  create new connection like      connection.start(); .At the end 100 message , 100 new connection. need to avoid that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating connection factory and then a connection in every `sendMessage` is probably not a good idea.

You can move this connection factory initialization part to a singleton util class which creates the connection factory only once when that util class is instantiated. Also use the `PooledConnectionFactory` instead of normal connection factory which creates a pool of connections, sessions and producers. The `sendMessage` should get the connection by calling `connectionUtil.getConnection()`. The rest of the code in `sendMessage` looks fine except you need to release the session, producer and connection in `finally` by calling `close()` on these objects.

[Pooled Connection Factory](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/jms/pool/PooledConnectionFactory.html)